# Web Aanlytics tool which support Rest/AJAX/WebSockets

Tags: web, analytics, web-analytics-tools

I am looking for a Web analytics tool which supports Single page applications, Multipage Web applications, mobile applications, native mobile applicaions (iOS etc..) captures all sorts of client server communication like REST calls, AJAX or WebSocket

I have tried some tools (can not name them) which doesnot suppport the WebSockets

Answer (score 0):

This is conflict to the Web Analytics tools I Know, this can be achieved by using tracing API of a tool if provided. Most tools provides tracking API by masking secure information one can push the events to the tool